# Error "Type does not exist in the namespace" after using of external library in this type

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, namespaces

It seems like there is tens of posts in the internet with such error. But I think my case is different, and all solutions I found do not help me.
I have type (I deleted all unimportant things but it changes nothing):

```
using ExternalLibrary;
namespace MyProject
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public ExternalLibrary.ExternalType myVar;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get access to this type in the XAML for further using it as a DataType:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MyWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MyClass x:Key="myKey"/>
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

and get error. If delete `using ExternalLibrary` and `myVar` from `MyClass`, all works. Use external library in class - and class does not exist in namespace. Delete the using of library - and class exist again. I use VisualStudio 2015, I had tried VS 2013 and error did not gone. I tried rebuild in debug, release, x86, x64, other frameworks, client profiles, different combines of namespaces and many other things. Is there solution of this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that if you delete the using statement the compiler is happy with `ExternalLibrary.ExternalType myVar`?

Comment: No, of course, you need delete this field too.

Comment: Interesting it works for me,I mean it works with a external library imported as you did.

Comment: @FreeMan Hmmm, so it is because of my library... But how can this be? (I'm using AutoCad API libraries for .NET)

Comment: Does it compile if you remove the resource from xaml?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova yes, it compiles

Comment: So maybe add the `ExternalLibrary` namespace to xaml?..

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I've tried to add `xmlns:ext="ExternalLibrary"` to XAML, it doesn't help :(

Comment: I've created new project with only things from my question and one library. Error is repeated stably. I'm using library `acdbmgd.dll` and its type `ObjectId`, if anyone will want to verify this himself.

Comment: Are you sure the dll is unblocked and the target processors for the dll and your project match?

Comment: I have a warnings that processor architectures MSIL and AMD64 does not match. But those libraries are only ones there, they are right. Do you think it can be matter?

Comment: You can change the target CPU of your project to x64.

Comment: I had looked at project's platforms again, more carefully, and it worked! I changed configuration to x64 in two places together - active solution platform and build project platform, unlike I have been doing before. Thank you for that idea :)

Comment: Cheers. I turned it into an answer so it can help others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out the `ExternalLibrary` in question was built for AMD64, while the project using it was targeting any CPU. The compiler couldn't find the class when building the project for 32 bit processors, hence the error. You can safety switch to targeting 64 bit processors, since it won't work on other machines anyway. To switch the target processor go Build -> Configuration Manager -> Platform -> x64

You may want to choose a different combination of platform for each of your projects depending on active solution platform. For example, if your solution is targeting x86, project A builds for x86, while project B for any CPU, but if the solution's targeting x64, both projects A and B build for x64. For more information see [Understanding Build Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/kkz9kefa.aspx).

If you're playing with these settings you may end up with an unexpected configuration, so it may make sense to have a look at what each project's targeting (you can do it in the Configuration Manager).